# JQuery Mobile Form data-ajax="false" auto submit with timer

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a form which will be automatically sent after some minutes. I use JQuery Mobile but want to send the form like a normal page not with the JQuery Mobile Ajax system. With "data-ajax=false" I can prevent JQuery from doing this.
But when I disable the JQuery Mobile function my custom JS Script to send the form does not work

$('form#question_form').submit();

This does nothing when "data-ajax" is set to false for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just before you send it you could remove the attribute data-ajax or set it to true and submit.

```
$('form#question_form').attr('data-ajax','true');
$('form#question_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

data-ajax is not the problem here. you may have having some problems with script. or you may returning false for submit action.  [data-ajax Jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/forms/forms-sample.html)

> Forms also accept attributes for transitions just like anchors, such
>   as data-transition="pop" and data-direction="reverse". To submit a
>   form without Ajax, you can either disable Ajax form handling globally,
>   or per form via the data-ajax="false" attribute. The target attribute
>   (as in target="_blank") is respected on forms as well, and will
>   default to the browser's handling of that target when the form
>   submits. Note that unlike anchors, the rel attribute is not allowed on
>   forms.

Comment: I've also had the same issue and it does seem to be a problem with ajax posting being turned off. We have it disabled globally with $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false and setting this to true on the page I'm posting with the submit method works